# Perl's equivalent to python exec?

Tags: python, perl

Python legal code:

```
  exec("def f():print 123"); f();
```

What is a Perl equivalent construction or how to bind symbols from eval to current scope from Perl's eval?

```
  eval("sub f(){ print 123;}"); f();
  "Undefined subroutine &main::f"
```

**Question is not actual, because it has misprint in it first definition.**

Comment: You *really* don't want to do that

Comment: How do you know what he wants to do?  He may be entering an obfuscated perl contest...

Comment: String `eval` is dangerous because it could lead to code injection. Don't use it unless you really know about security. See `perldoc perlsec` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html

Comment: Mmm, what I wanted is dynamic execution of forming code like python's exec...Form a code and feed it to eval. No I'm not taking a part in obfuscated contest and It is not part of web project....

Comment: perl security is absolutely not interesting for me at current moment of my life, but thanks for link) it was really just misprint in script, and quite perl interpreter behavior.

Comment: Security should be a concern for all programmers. If you're going to do something risky, at less know the risks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but string eval will put the function in the package namespace (and will redefine if there is already a function by that name). If you only need this in one spot:

```
my $f = sub { my $v = shift; sub { print $v } }->(123);
...
$f->();
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

sub f () { print 456 };

eval "sub f() { print 123 }";

f();

my $f = sub { my $v = shift; sub { print $v } }->(123);

$f->();
```

Output:

```
Subroutine f redefined at (eval 1) line 1.
123
123
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed trick with anonymous function, but I only made a misprint in subroutine definition)

Comment: Is there a reason for empty prototype? `sub () {..}`

Comment: I think so, there is empty prototype + some colon sign + quiet model of eval invocation in Perl=> all of it lead to unnecessary question in stackoverflow)

Comment: @Сухой27 It's early in the morning here. "prototypes have no influence ... on indirect subroutine calls".

Comment: Np, I thought I've missed something.

Comment: @Сухой27 Sorry for the confusion. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You have a wrong subroutine declaration. Try:

```
eval("sub f { print 123 }"); f();
```

See also: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Comment: I have misprint. eval("sub f {print 123;}"); f(); works fine to me